# Need help on architecting iPhone/Android App

Tags: java, iphone, android

Could someone please help me with how should I go about architecting a iPhone or Android application? I am into enterprise java development for many years and have architected many solutions in it. However, I have never been involved with mobile development. I have a good application idea that I would like to implement. My initial thought is, I am looking to utilize db + NoSQL, implement services and want to have iPhone/Android app make calls to the web services for different needs.

How should I architect this? Any pointers to help me started on it? Most of the search I am doing online is all about gaming in iPhone/Android and I am not able to find any solid pattern/architecture that would guide me on how to implement. Could anyone please help?

Also, is there any good link for implementing enterprise applications on iPhone and Android?

Comment: Let me rephrase - What I am really looking is how are they generally designed. I know what is needed in terms of machine/SDK/account requirements. I am trying to look into what type of software architecture is generally followed for apps for Android/iPhone. For example, for Android, I read that there is no direct web service support and if you want to use SOAP you have to use something like K-SOAP, which is not that good. Could some one guide if they have experience designing application for Android/iPhone device how did their architecture look like and if you have any diagram of diff layers.

Answer (score 3):

I can't speak to Android, but the best way to get up to speed on iOS development is:

1. Buy/Borrow/Steal a Mac. You don't need a 27" iMac, a Mac Mini will suffice.
2. Get an Apple developer account. Pay the $99 for it.
3. Watch the Stanford University lectures on iPhone development, which are available for free from iTunes University. This is a comprehensive introduction to developing iPhone applications, and is well worth watching every second of it.
4. Watch the WWDC videos from this year and last year about iOS topics that interest you. There are tons of amazing techniques and tips in there.

This will get you up to speed on the basics, the differences between Java and Objective-C and how iPhone development is unique.

Comment: very accurate steps. Totally agree. Mac can develop Android applications too. First, buy an Android phone; then, download Android SDK & Eclipse IDE; next, learn from tutorials ( there are tutorials around, but not as tidy as iOS ones ); last, make your app. Web Services can be in most web-based languages, so my suggestion is to make the Web Services first, then work on your apps.